# "Bella calligrafia": si può dire, o sarebbe meglio "bella grafìa"?

Tags: word-usage

Sebbene sia madrelingua italiano, ho un dubbio che mi assilla da tempo, riguardo l'utilizzo di una parola...spero possiate aiutarmi! Mi riferisco, in particolare, alla parola "calligrafia".

Fin dalle scuole elementari, ho sempre sentito parlare di "bella calligrafia". Effettivamente lo si dice, quando si vuole sottolineare la bella scrittura di qualcuno.

Ma su alcune fonti, ricordo di aver letto che "bella calligrafia" sarebbe errato, perché la parola "calligrafia" significa di per sé "bella scrittura" e, pertanto, bisognerebbe dire "bella grafia". Ma, all'atto pratico, non ho mai sentito nessuno dire "hai una bella grafia" in una conversazione reale.

Qualcuno saprebbe fare chiarezza sul suo utilizzo? Grazie!

Comment: Quando io andavo a scuola si usava dire "hai una bella calligrafia", che sarebbe come dire "hai una bella bella grafia". Però penso che "call" sia inglese, quindi noi italiani non abbiamo associato la parola "call" a "bella", parlo naturalmente per me, certamente l'Accademia della Crusca l’avrà fatto.
Ho saputo anche allora che era errato, ma non mi ricordo che i maestri o maestre ci abbiano mai corretto questa espressione, "hai una bella calligrafia". Era solo per dire la mia opinione, so anch’io per sentito dire che c’era una materia che si chiamava calligrafia.

Comment: @Francesco: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Solo una piccola nota: *calli-* viene dal greco καλός, non dall'inglese

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buon giorno.

Calligrafia è la composizione di calli e grafia che appunto vuol dire bella scrittura. Quindi, sì, dire bella calligrafia sarebbe come dire bella bella scrittura: un doppio inutile.

La pratica, poi, come succede spesso, è diversa dalla teoria: la maggior parte delle persone non sanno il significato di calli-, quindi usano calligrafia con il significato di grafia. Quindi, per loro, è necessario aggiungere "bella" per poter dire bella grafia.

Quindi, per riassumere: il modo corretto di dire e scrivere sarebbe bella grafia ma dato che pochi usano la parola grafia e molti la confondono con la parola calligrafia, nel parlato si sente quasi sempre bella calligrafia.

Spero di essere stato utile.

Comment: Grazie mille Andrea, molto utile! Come spesso accade, c'è una disparità tra lingua parlata e lingua scritta, combinata a un'etimologia che spesso si ignora...grazie ancora.

Comment: *In teoria non c'è alcuna differenza tra pratica e teoria. In pratica ce n'è.*

Answer (score 9):

Aldo Gabrielli invitava a non essere pedanti. A una maestra che gli poneva una simile domanda rispondeva:

> L'osservazione è teoricamente giusta. [Salto una parte in cui spiega l'etimo di “calligrafia”.] Ma presto il significato della voce si dilatò per assumere quello più generico di maniera di scrivere, di scrittura; e senza tener più conto di quel prefisso che indicava appunto bellezza, si cominciò a dire «bella calligrafia», non solo, ma anche «brutta calligrafia», «orribile calligrafia», che parrebbero davvero un controsenso. Dunque, la mia maestrina metta da parte le sue paure, e stia tranquilla: in un compito scolastico «bella calligrafia», «brutta calligrafia» non sarà mai da segnare errore.

(Aldo Gabrielli, *Si dice o non si dice?*, Mondadori 1969)

Comment: Molto interessante questa citazione! Grazie mille, è un'ottima spiegazione.

Comment: @Andrea inoltre, e' abbastanza inusuale usare, per una brutta grafia, il termine cacografia. Questo per dire che grafia da solo e' raramente usato, e di solito appunto calligrafia == grafia.

Comment: Andrea e @DiegoMartinoia: Aggiungo che “grafia” è così poco usato in questo senso, che anche Gabrielli nella sua spiegazione non lo usa, bensì parla di “maniera di scrivere” e di “scrittura”.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: Grazie, non conoscevo questo termine! Un po' come cacofonìa per i suoni...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that once in some Italian schools people had to study "Calligrafia", which was simply the name of the subject: it meant that yours could be ugly and the school was going to help you to make it beautiful.
So "calligrafia" has meant "grafia" for a very long time.
My mother (before the Second World War) certainly had that subject, which was considered very important. I didn't have that subject, but I still had to learn "Bella Calligrafia" during my Elementary (Primary) School when we had only one teacher (wonderful: sometimes she was almost like a second mother to us) and no separate subjects.

Please see: http://lascuoladiunavolta.altervista.org/43/

Vorrei aggiungere che in alcune scuole italiane la "Calligrafia" era semplicemente una materia di studio: la tua poteva essere brutta e la scuola ti avrebbe aiutato a farla diventare bella.
Quindi il termine "Calligrafia" è stato usato da tanti anni per dire grafia. Mia madre (prima dell'ultima guerra) certamente aveva quella materia di studio, che era considerata molto importante. A me non è toccata la materia, ma ho dovuto comunque imparare la "Bella Calligrafia" durante le mie Scuole Elementari, quando avevamo una sola insegnante (fantastico: qualche volta era quasi come una seconda mamma per noi) e non c'erano materie formalmente separate.

Comment: Grazie, ho apprezzato molto il link al blog con tanto di immagine di repertorio! Quindi, stando alla fonte, "calligrafia" significava proprio "bella grafia" (_Far acquistare agli alunni l’abitudine di una scrittura chiara e snella [...]_), quindi ha "perso" l'accezione originaria con il tempo.